# How to describe a shared VPC and define its subnets in GCP via terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have created two shared VPCs for my organization, one for prod and one for non-prod usage.

For the these shared VPCs I want to create a description and define subnets, but I cannot find the right entries in terraform for these elements.

I.e. Here is how I defined the resource block to specify the host project (and create a shared VPC) :

```
resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project" "dev-shared-shared-vpc-host" {
  provider = google.as_network_admin
  project  = google_project.dev-shared-vpc-host.project_id
}
```

Now when I try to create the subnet :

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "dev-subnetwork" {
  provider      = google.as_network_admin
  name          = var.vpc_and_subnet_info.for_dev_env.subnetwork.name
  ip_cidr_range = var.vpc_and_subnet_info.for_dev_env.subnetwork.ip_cidr_range
  region        = var.region
  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = var.vpc_and_subnet_info.for_dev_env.subnetwork.secondary_ip_range.name
    ip_cidr_range = var.vpc_and_subnet_info.for_dev_env.subnetwork.secondary_ip_range.ip_cidr_range
  }
  network = google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project.dev-shared-shared-vpc-host.id
  project = google_project.dev-shared-vpc-host.id
}
```

I get an error like

```
╷
│ Error: Error creating Subnetwork: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.network': 'projects/projects/<redacted_project_id>/global/networks/<redacted_project_id>'. The URL is malformed., invalid
│
│   with google_compute_subnetwork.dev-subnetwork,
│   on networking.tf line 5, in resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "dev-subnetwork":
│    5: resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "dev-subnetwork" {
│
```

Obviously the `projects/projects/..` is messing up the network parameter, but in [the documentation for google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_shared_vpc_host_project) there isn't any other output other than `id`. And for the input arguments there is no `description`. However, when I try to manually create the shared VPC, I can enter a description, and create a subnet.

Mind you, the [google_compute_network](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/compute_network) that creates regular VPCs is quite well documented and the subnet that I defined above works well with it.

EDIT :

Fixing the `project` argument into `project = google_project.dev-shared-vpc-host.project_id` instead of `id` removes the `projects/projects/...` network error, but gives this error instead :

```
╷
│ Error: Error creating Subnetwork: googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/<redacted_project_id>/global/networks/<redacted_project_id>' was not found, notFound
│
│   with google_compute_subnetwork.dev-subnetwork,
│   on networking.tf line 5, in resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "dev-subnetwork":
│    5: resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "dev-subnetwork" {
│
╵
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have misunderstood the creation of a shared VPC via `google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project`, this does not **create** a vpc perse, but only designates a project as the host project, thus **sharing** a vpc that must exist beforehand.

Therefore I should have created a `google_compute_network` beforehand, here is the HCL necessary to achieve what I wanted in the question :

```
resource "google_compute_network" "dev-vpc-network" {
  provider                = google.as_network_admin
  name                    = var.vpc_and_subnet_info.for_dev_env.vpc.name
  auto_create_subnetworks = var.vpc_and_subnet_info.for_dev_env.vpc.auto_create_subnetworks
  project                 = google_project.dev-shared-vpc-host.project_id
  description             = var.vpc_and_subnet_info.for_dev_env.vpc.description
}
resource "google_compute_shared_vpc_host_project" "dev-shared-shared-vpc-host" {
  provider = google.as_network_admin
  project  = google_project.dev-shared-vpc-host.project_id
}
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "dev-subnetwork" {
  provider      = google.as_network_admin
  name          = var.vpc_and_subnet_info.for_dev_env.subnetwork.name
  ip_cidr_range = var.vpc_and_subnet_info.for_dev_env.subnetwork.ip_cidr_range
  region        = var.region
  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = var.vpc_and_subnet_info.for_dev_env.subnetwork.secondary_ip_range.name
    ip_cidr_range = var.vpc_and_subnet_info.for_dev_env.subnetwork.secondary_ip_range.ip_cidr_range
  }
  network = google_compute_network.dev-vpc-network.id
  project = google_project.dev-shared-vpc-host.project_id
}
```

Of course, in these examples I used variables declared in **.tfvars** to fill in the name, and other arguments needed in the resource blocks.